# Twitter API results into database

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, twitter

I am looking to make multiple queries with the Twitter API, which I believe i need to wrap into an array as I have around 100 usernames.

the url i will be using is http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=username and from there I can get the followers information and username which is all i want to retrieve.

The way I believe I need to do it is by having the usernames in a database and run an array around the API lookup which then spits out the results? I also need to store the results into a database which i also understand I can include in the array.

Does anyone know if this has been done before? and if I am going a long the right lines. Any feedback would be very much appreciated.

Damien

Answer (score 0):

First of, keep in mind that twitter have a 'query limit', this means that you are able to do N requests to twitter api per minute, if you exceed it you will be penalized with some time without responses from them.

About the way you want to do it, I think it's ok, if you want to store it in a database, you can but it depends in what you want to do with the data.
I suppose you read the docs, so you can query the twitter api with 100 users per request, then you got the data and do whatever you want with it.

I'm sure there are some script to provide this functionality, but... come on! it's not so hard to do it by yourself!

Good luck!

Comment: The rate limit is 150/hr from an app (without an authenticated user), or 350/hr per authenticated user.